# Prevent 404 error when multiple user downloading same PDF

Tags: c#, webforms, http-status-code-404

I have a PDF file located on the server. The user of our web app can access to it via a simple link. Some of our users are experiencing 404 error file or directory not found at random times. The error page comes back in a split second, the page is not hanging... If you refresh the page it will eventually go through and view it in the browser. My guess is the 404 is raised because someone else is trying to access the file at the same exact time? How could I prevent this?

This is a C# 4.6 Webforms application running with IIS 7.

Comment: if the file were locked or something that impeded the access the server would not return a not found error but an internal error. Is the file located in some network storage which the server can lose access to?

Comment: How are you service the PDF file via static content or custom code for file download? Is there any load balancing involved?

Comment: The only real way of finding the root cause is use Sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see that specific error that is being returned.  I suspect that 404 is being caused by the DNS login server not responding back quick enough to verify credentials.  You may want to increase the timeout to see if that helps.  I do not think it is due to multiple users trying to read file at same time especially if you are getting file/directory not found.

Comment: @Gusman The file is located on the server in a folder of teh web application itself.

Comment: @vendettamit the file is served statically with a href pointing to it.

Comment: @jdweng I am not sure how to adjust the timeout. Would you have a resource page maybe for me? i quickly researched and did not find anything relevant...

Comment: See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx